# Can't get attachments in outlook mail from bugzilla

Tags: outlook, bugzilla

I am a new user in bugzilla and I'd like to edit email templates. I successfully edited the email contents with my wish. But, there is a problem I can't display/view the attachments in the outlook mail. It shows the message that :-

> **Created attachment 12
>
>   --> attachment.cgi?id=12 
>   ... Attached document sample descriptions ...**

Can anyone please help me to identify which template file should I edited for this ? or Is that option is not supported by bugzilla ?

Please feel free to comment with this

Thanks,
Jyothis T S
jyothis@iris-llc.com

Comment: What version of Bugzilla? Which template did you edit and what did you change?